# Regex match any js number

Tags: javascript, regex

So as an exercise I wanted to match any JS number. This is the one I could come up with:

```js
/^(-?)(0|([1-9]\d*?|0)(\.\d+)?)$/
```

This however doesn't match the new syntax with underscore separators (`1_2.3_4`). I tried a couple of things but I couldn't come up with something that would work. How could I express all JS numbers in one regex?

Comment: There is `.isNaN` method in JS for this purpose, not `regex`.

Comment: @Kosh this is just for fun, not for practicality.

Comment: I didn't know about [this](https://v8.dev/features/numeric-separators)...is it useful?

Comment: There's much more valid JS number formats: 123, .20, -.1, +0123, 5e2, 0b111, 0xff ...so this is not easy.

Comment: @aMarCruz whoops, I forgot about those :P

Comment: @zer00ne when you have big numbers then yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the format in the question, you could use:

```
^-?\d+(?:_\d+)*(?:\.\d+(?:_\d+)*)?$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gZZTd1/1).

Or allowing only a single leading zero:

```
^-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:_\d+)*(?:\.\d+(?:_\d+)*)?$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `-?` Match an optional `-`
- `(?:0|[1-9]\d*)` Match either `0` or 1-9 and optional digits
- `(?:_\d+)*` Optionally repeat matching `_` and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\.\d+(?:_\d+)*` Match `.` and 1+ digits and optionally repeat matching `_` and 1+ digits
- `)?` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wTl3RM/1).

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
^(-?)(0|([1-9]*?(\_)?(\d)|0|)(\.\d+)?(\_)?(\d))$
```